# One table with a type field or separate tables for limited number of types?

Tags: best-practices

I have the `services` table and the `products` table, they have identical fields; `price`, `description`, etc.

Is it better to have one table with a `type` field that can either be `product` or `service` **nothing else**

or to have two tables one for `products` and one for `services`?

Comment: Please define what you mean by `products` and `services`, what data will be stored in each of the tables. Keep the tables separate , but do not keep redundant data in both of them, if `products` <> `services`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better you keep it in one table with a **TYPE** field to separate the product and Services. But this can be different with the project domain. You need to think about the ease of use of the data from both types as well as the load of data with the growth.

e.g.: You have different workflow for Products and Services to process and no direct connection in between; go for a separate table.